# ignore node_modules on cordova build

Tags: android, cordova, npm

How can I stop cordova from trying to copy my www/node_modules folder to platforms/{android/iOS}/www the when doing a build command like this:

```
     cordova build android
```

This seems like a relatively straight forward thing that everybody would want to do, but everything I have found does not seem to work.

This is particularly an issue when doing a build for android as something in my node folder is causing the build to fail.

I am hoping there is a way to leverage the config.xml file for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include node_modules in /www. It should be one level up. My guess is that you initialized your npm project from the incorrect directory.

Comment: I'm only using npm for grunt and bower, Is it ok to manually move the folder up one directory, or should I delete it and start over from the directory one level up?

Comment: I would just start fresh. When you initially ran `npm init` it generated a `package.json` for you. Make sure thats in your project root as a sibling to `/www`. In short: `package.json` and `node_modules` should both be at the root

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as answer because that was the route I took. I just started a fresh directory, npm init, and moved my www stuff manually. All is good now, thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 2):

Have your build process that needs `node_modules` for Grunt and Bower run in some other folder in your project, one that is at the same level in the folder hierarchy as `www` perhaps.  Then at the end of your build process, have the build tools copy the built artifacts into `www` before kicking off `cordova build <platform name>`.